# Pages files split into pieces

Tags: fine-uploader

Occasionally when using FineUploader to upload .pages files, they got split into their components.

[image]

You'll see what I mean in that image. That was supposed be one .pages file. Any ideas on how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, in some cases, you are uploading a folder containing the component files you have mentioned.  In that case, provided the browser supports folder uploads (Chrome/Opera), each file in the folder will be sent in a separate request.  If you are simply uploading a single file, Fine Uploader will *always* send a single upload request, containing the file.  If the file is split into pieces in that case, the issue is specific to your server code.

Comment: Hi Ray - This is not triggered by uploading a folder, though I am using Chrome. This is just a typical .pages file that is being split into multiple pieces. For some reason, the .pages files seem to be recognized as folder.

Answer (score 0):

Older .pages files are actually packages: folders in OS X which are represented as a single file in Finder and open in an application when double-clicked. You can see this by changing the extension to something other than .pages and the file will appear like any other folder.

Newer versions of Pages (5.5 or later) saves files as actual documents which are like other files, except when the file is greater than 500 MB in size, as packages are more efficient then. You will see the following message when this occurs, giving you the option:

[image]

Older versions of Pages allows you to change this option in Preferences, whilst newer versions of Pages allows you to change this on-the-fly:

> You can switch between a single file and a package at any time. Open your file. Then choose File > Advanced > Change File Type and select the type you'd like to use.

<sup>Source: http://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202887</sup>

Comment: Interesting. Is there a way to have FineUploader not recognize these files then? I have folders turned off in the uploader config, but they are still recognized as folders and split.

Comment: @TJC You can't "turn folders off".  There is no such configuration option in Fine Uploader.  If you drop a folder, Fine Uploader will process it.  You can exclude specific file types, but that would not apply here if you are actually dropping a folder.  If you only want to upload your document as one file, then you will have to modify the .pages file to ensure it is not a package.

Comment: hmmm. for some reason i was under the impression that folder support could be disabled. The issue is that my end users are not going to know the difference between a .pages file that is a package and a .pages file that is a single file, and I have no way to determine that programmatically either. Any thoughts on a way to detect and disable this?

Comment: Disabling folder support is not the solution you are looking for.  That doesn't change the fact that some of your pages files are actually folders.